# Question regarding baby do Carmo's definition of a regular surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, definition

The following is part of baby do Carmo´s definition of a regular surface (at the beginning of the second chapter):

[image: First part of do Carmo's definition]
[image: Second part of do Carmo's definition]

---

This seems to imply that any differentiable function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must have continuous partial differential derivatives of all orders. **Is this true? If so, how can it be shown?**

---

What I do know is that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at a point $x\in U$, then its partial derivatives exist at $x$. Also, if the partial derivatives are continuous at $x$, then the function $f$ is (total) differentiable at $x$.

Comment: Very simply, he's taking the word "differentiable" to mean *smooth* or $C^\infty$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I did not think to read the last bit as a _definition_ of what it means to be differentiable. Thanks.

Comment: Should I close/delete the question?

Comment: I think it’s ok to leave the question up, as this point might also confuse future readers of do Carmo.

Comment: I’ll go ahead and put my comment as an answer so that the question will go off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoCarmo is taking the word *differentiable* to mean *smooth* or $C^\infty$.